# How to set up a easy-to-use proxy for the whole system with WinXP client and server?

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, proxy, remote-access, nat

I am working together intensively with a colleague on the Canary Islands. We speak through live messenger and work together using a RDP software. She has frequent problems with connections to certain big-name and small-name sites (amongst others live.com, google.com, gmx.de) very likely to be caused by the spanish provider (the connections simply time out, this has been going on for weeks already). I have been thinking about setting up my computer as a proxy to make these connections work. I have a DSL connection and am behind a NAT capable router that I control.

Does anybody know a simple, "one-click" way to transport ALL network traffic through a remote proxy? Without having to set proxy settings for each application that uses the internet?

VPN is not an option, because I am behind a firewall that supports protocol 47 and such, but I have never succeeded in getting an incoming VPN connection to work. I can however redirect normal traffic using NAT.
A VPN solution that does not need strange protocols would also be an option.

Comment: An answer to this question might help .. http://serverfault.com/questions/78951/networking-software-testing-how-do-i-use-a-proxy-server

Comment: Thanks, but if I understand it correctly, that is for setting up a "normal" proxy only. I'm looking for the easiest solution to transport all traffic through sa proxy without having to set up the applications manually - without VPN for the above mentioned reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [OpenVPN ALS](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/openvpn-als/) This is an Open Source continuation of SSL Explorer. Basically it is a Java Web VPN that operates entirely over SSL so you just need to port-forward 443 on your firewall and you are in business.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried something like [opendns](http://www.opendns.com/) yet?  i'd point the main dns server down there to obtain dns info from an outside source(other than her local isp) first.  then if that doesn't work, route that traffic through a public proxy.  there's plenty of free proxies available in the US, Europe, etc.  here's a list: [Proxy List 1](http://www.proxy4free.com/page1.html)

Comment: Actually, yes: Switching to OpenDNS brought a notable increase in speed and connectivity, but some sites still don't work (a traceroute or ping show that the IP address is resolved, but any connection times out).

Comment: you think it could be that the sites are timing out traffic to her based on her country location when they go through the final handshake to deliver traffic back to her?  if that's the case, i think she may have to go through a proxy like the one mentioned above.  it's a very similar process to the opendns solution, but could have better results....

Comment: @anonMan: Exactly, that's what I'm looking for: A proxying solution that she can switch on/off with as little hassle as possible, with the remote proxy being my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that she can simply turn on and have all her network traffic automatically reroute through your computer, without application by application, then what you are looking for is a VPN. Without knowing a bit more why you haven't been able to successfully set up a VPN, I'm not sure we can help much.

[OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net) is the type of VPN I normally use, and you are able to set it up to listen on other ports than 1194/UDP, the default. I guess the question is, does your ISP block incoming ports, or is it a misconfiguration that causes the VPN to not work. You could forward 1194/UDP to your computer and set up an OpenVPN server to see if it would work.

Otherwise, she might look into a VPN service, which would cost money, but would allow access. *However,* what I would do in these circumstances is have her contact her ISP and get them to fix the service.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [proxyfire](http://www.proxifier.com/), works great, it's not free though

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using the Bitvise products, free for personal use.

This would require setting up :

- On your machine : the [WinSSHD SSH server](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd)
- On your friend's : the [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) SSH and SFTP client for Windows

From the doc of Tunnelier:

> Tunnelier is a powerful SSH2 port
>   forwarding client with many features,
>   including:
> Dynamic tunneling via
>   integrated proxy supporting SOCKS4,
>   SOCKS4A, SOCKS5 and HTTP CONNECT proxy
>   tunneling protocols. Configure your
>   applications to connect to target
>   hosts through Tunnelier's proxy, and
>   no manual tunneling rules need be
>   configured.

I've never used this combination, so I hope it answers your question, but you'll have to try it in order to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Treewalk DNS](http://ntcanuck.com/downloads.htm) ,once you set it up it makes DNS work automatically.It'is the best for Windows XP but does not support Vista and Win 7.

Comment: Cheers, but DNS is a part of the problem already solved using openDNS. Many connections are resolved to an IP address but time out. I need an actual Proxy to circumvent that.

Comment: Treewalk is more efficient way to get rid of proxy problems.I tried opendns also but Treewalk cannot be compared to opendns.Opendns (manual) is not a good solution.Treewalk does everything automatically.Just set up and it does all.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, Chrome, Safari or maxthon you can use this: [IE proxy switcher](http://soft-net.net/IEProxySwitch.aspx)